# c#: Access a file image when a combobox index is selected

Tags: c#, combobox, filenames

I have to access photos from a file whenever I select a Combobox Index. the photo and information related to it needs to be displayed on the form. I am unsure how to access the file photo using a pathname.

Below I have a portion of my code. The combobox contains city names.

```
private void cmbHouseList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(cmbHouseList.SelectedIndex.ToString() == ofdHouse.FileName)
        {
            txtAddress.Text = house.Street;
            txtCity.Text = house.City;
            txtZip.Text = house.Postal;
            txtPrice.Text = house.Price.ToString();

        }

    }
```

Comment: I have no idea what the filenames might be, but is there *any* chance they would be named "1", "0", "3" and so forth?  Fire up your debugger - that is what you are checking/testing

Comment: the file names are Glendale, Mississauga, Brampton, Markham and Oakdale. The cityNames are the same. I have to access to photos via filename.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your question is **How to access the file photo using a pathname**.

The answer is

```
string Pathname; //Whatever pathname.
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(Pathname);
```

Bang! Voila! Good luck!!!